# How to plot real-time graph, with both axis dependent on time?

Tags: python, animation, numpy, matplotlib, real-time

I want to create an animation showing a diver jumps into water.

By the given parameters of original height of diver from the water, `h` and his mass, `m`, I defined a procedure in Python to calculate the moment he touches the water, `Tc` .

Knowing that he jumps vertically, X axis is fixed, and
Y axis obeys equation (1/2)*g*t^2 + h (g is gravitational constant)

How do I plot a graph while time `t` is in range(`Tc`), X and Y axis shows the projection the diver?  (`x` is fixed and `y` depends on time `t`)

In the graphic window we are supposed to see a dot that 'jumps' from certain height vertically downwards, without seeing the line/trace of projection.

Here is part of my work. I don't know where to introduce `Tc` in the procedure:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.empty(n) ; x.fill(1)   # the vertical position is fixed on x-axis
    y = 0.5*g*i^2 + h             # the equation of diver's displacement on y axis

    line.set_data(x, y) 
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
        frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Edit:

Here is the whole program. I applied and modified the suggestion given by @Mike Muller, but it didn't work. I don’t understand where it goes wrong. Hope you can clarify my doubts.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from math import *  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def Plongeon():
    h = input("height = ")
    h = float(h)

    m = input(" mass = ")
    m = float(m)
    global g
    g = 9.8
    g = float(g)

    global Tc        #calculate air time, Tc
    Tc = sqrt(2*h/g)
    Tc = round(Tc,2)
    print Tc



    # First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, h+1))  #ymax : initial height+1
    line, = ax.plot([], [], ' o', lw=2)


    Tc = int(Tc+1)       #make Tc an integer to be used later in def get_y()
    xs = [1] # the vertical position is fixed on x-axis
    ys = [h, h]

    # initialization function: plot the background of each frame
    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    # animation function.  This is called sequentially
    def animate(y):
        ys[-1] = y
        line.set_data(xs, ys)
        return line,

    def get_y():
        for step in range(Tc):
            t = step / 100.0
            y = -0.5*g*t**2 + h  # the equation of diver's displacement on y axis
        yield y

    # call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=get_y, interval=100)

    plt.show()
Plongeon()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer based on original question

You need to use a generator to produce your y data. This works:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], ' o', lw=2)
g = 9.81
h = 2
tc = 200
xs = [1] # the vertical position is fixed on x-axis
ys = [h, h]


# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(y):
    ys[-1] = y
    line.set_data(xs, ys)
    return line,

def get_y():
  for step in range(tc):
    t = step / 100.0
    y = -0.5*g*t**2 + h  # the equation of diver's displacement on y axis
    yield y

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=get_y, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Integrated answer

This should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from math import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def Plongeon():
    h = float(input("height = "))
    g = 9.81

    #calculate air time, Tc
    Tc = sqrt(2 * h / g)

    # First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, h+1))  #ymax : initial height+1
    line, = ax.plot([], [], ' o', lw=2)

    step = 0.01  # animation step
    xs = [1]  # the vertical position is fixed on x-axis
    ys = [h]


    # animation function.  This is called sequentially
    def animate(y):
        ys[-1] = y
        line.set_data(xs, ys)
        return line,

    def get_y():
        t = 0
        while t <= Tc:
            y = -0.5 * g * t**2 + h  # the equation of diver's displacement on y axis
            yield y
            t += step

    # call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=get_y, interval=100)

    plt.show()
Plongeon()
```

I removed unneeded lines. No need for `global`. Also mass has never been used anywhere in the program.

This is the most important part:

```
def get_y():
     t = 0
     while t <= Tc:
         y = -0.5 * g * t**2 + h 
         yield y
         t += step
```

You need to advance your time by an increment.

Comment: thank you very much, but it didn't work on my program and i guess maybe there's some part i didn't use the right notation. i posted my complete program under the question, hope you can clear my doubt.

Comment: thanks once again, i'm a beginner so sometimes i failed to see simple error in the program, I'm glad you pointed it out. By the way, I converted Tc into an integer so it can be run in the loop while. What does    ys = [1e10, h]   means? . The graph couldn't run, and i replaced with just   ys = [h]   , i even tried with your initial suggestion   ys = [h, h]  . It couldn't run either. I don't know how to identify error.

Comment: Changed to `ys = [h]`. Was a leftover from an experiment. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: No need to convert `Tc` into an integer. We use a while loop and calculate the current time with `t += step` until we reach `Tc`.

Comment: Hello, your first program works but not the second one, i have been trying working on it with my partners  but in vain, can you lend a hand please? And what is "def init() " for?

Comment: The `init()` is not needed. Removed.

Comment: It works. Really appreciate your help. Bon week-end.